# Can an existing employer force use of personal vehicle?

Tags: employment, business, insurance, vehicle, employer

If an employee refuses to use their own car for business purposes (although it was never mentioned before commencement of employment and is not mentioned in the employment contract), is it possible to dismiss them or begin disciplinary proceedings (UK)?

Further information: The employer is offering to pay mileage at a rate that covers fuel and wear and tear, however the employee would be transporting children to and from school and argues that it would not cover damage and cleaning caused by the children, as well as generally not wanting to use their car regardless of expenses.

Comment: Transporting children that assumedly aren't the employee's? Whose insurance would cover that?

Comment: Mine probably would. But i don't live in the UK.

Comment: In the U.S. the answer would be that the employer could insist on this, but the U.K. has a more regulatory culture.

Comment: @JAB Business insurance, organised by the employee but paid for by the company

Comment: Still nothing on this....